# What does protecting your note do?

Tags: bloodborne

There is an option in Bloodborne to write a note to remind yourself and others online of hidden treasure etc. Within the `Notebook > Notes Made` option, you can press [image] to protect a note.

What does this option do? Is there a maximum number of notes you can make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a limit of 10 notes that you can have active at any time. Once you reach the limit, older notes are overwritten (presumably in order of writing).

It's worth it to save good notes that provide you with a lot of Fair ratings, so they'll continue to provide healing bonuses.

See also: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/bloodborne/comments/30exiq/remember_to_protect_your_best_notes/)